# Automate fixing of default link text

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2633483/best-approach-for-gpgpu-cuda-opencl-in-java/3307145#3307145), the link text is literally `link text`, but they've provided a meaningful optional title (such as `Particles Demo`).

I could fix it, but can't we have the correction of such answers automated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we should be more worried about fixing this user, or simply clicking "edit", than some fancy programmatic solution.